# C# Method Property Param

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, parameters, properties

I want to add a property as a parameter.

```
    /// <summary>
    ///     Permet de passer à la prochaine valeur de la <see 
    cref="Dimension" />.
    /// </summary>
    public void DimensionSuivante()
    {
        if (Dimension == enuDimension.Petite)
            Dimension = enuDimension.Maximale;
        else
            Dimension += 1;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Permet de passer à la prochaine valeur de la <see cref="Qualite" 
    />.
    /// </summary>
    public void QualiteSuivante()
    {
        if (Qualite == enuQualite.Faible)
            Qualite = enuQualite.Excellente;
        else
            Qualite += 1;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Permet de passer à la prochaine valeur de la <see 
    cref="Sensibilite" />.
    /// </summary>
    public void SensibiliteSuivante()
    {
        if (Sensibilite == enuSensibilite.ISO_800)
            Sensibilite = enuSensibilite.ISO_64;
        else
            Sensibilite += 1;
    }
```

*These methods gets alot repetitive, so i wanted to create a new method that we pass a `Property` as a `parameter`. I have no idea what the `syntax` would be.
I've tried adding the `object` before the `param`. Here's the method i have so far.*

```
    private void GetPropertyNext(PropertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyName == FirstOfEnu)
            PropertyName = LastOfEnu;
        else
            PropertyName += 1;
    }
```

Comment: In last code you need to define variable name after PropertyName.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass properties by reference. See [How to pass properties by reference in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1867708) and [C# Pass a property by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2374963).

But usually, you don't need to. And that's the case here. I think your method should look more like this:

```
static T IncrementEnum<T>(T value)
{
    int[] values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<int>().ToArray();
    int i = (int)(object)value,
        min = values.Min(),
        max = values.Max();

    return (T)(object)(i == max ? min : i + 1);
}
```

Then you can call it like:

```
Dimension  = IncrementEnum(Dimension);
```

The above method is somewhat costly, because each time you call it, it has to determine the `min` and `max` values. You can encapsulate it in a generic type, and initialize those values in the static constructor, if this is something where that performance overhead would be an issue.